# How to emulate iPod Touch in Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, ipod-touch

I'm using the "Emulator" feature of Chrome's Developer Tools, and I see a dropdown menu where I can select which device I want to emulate.  I see many Apple devices listed (Apple iPad 1,2,3 and 4, several models of iPhone, etc.  However I don't see any listing for the iPod touch (see attached screenshot).

My question is, which of the Apple devices is closest in screen dimension to the iPod Touch?

[image: Options available under "Device" dropdown menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 4 is the same screen resolution as older iPod Touches.

The iPhone 5 is the same screen resolution as the newest iPod Touch.